# Flutter wait for Firestore to complete

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using flutter with firebase to create an app. The function below gets some data from my firebase database, but the problem is that it takes too long to get the data. How can make sure the app waits for the firebase getting data to finish first before proceeding?

I would like to do something like an await, but I don't know if I can do:

```
await Firestore.instance...
```

Code:

```
  void getData() {

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .document('document')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {

          var count = ds.data.length;
          for(var i = 0; i < count; i ++){
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('collection')
                .document('document')
                .get()
                .then((DocumentSnapshot dss) {
                // do something

            });
          }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why are you fetching documents twice in the code?

Comment: I need the data nested in the previous document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use await, you have to make your function async :

```
Future<void> getData() async {
```

Then yes, you can do

```
var result = await Firestore.instance.collection...
```

instead of handling the Future result in the then() callback. The next line will not be executed until the Future is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to await for the firestore to return data.
and then return it.

```
Future getData() async {
  DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('collection')
      .document('document')
      .get();
  final data = ds.//do something with document snapshot

  return data;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does a query with 'where' condition work with await?