# Wait for query inside for loop - Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have this function that creates a list of users from their ids. A query is made for each id to get the information from Firebase RTDB.

```
static List<FrediUser> formattedParticipantListFromIDs(List<String> participantIDs) {
List<FrediUser> formattedParticipants = [];

for (String id in participantIDs) {
  dbQuery(2, 'users', id).once().then((value) {
    formattedParticipants.add(FrediUser.fromMap(value.snapshot.value as Map));
  });
}

print(formattedParticipants.length);
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  print(formattedParticipants.length);
});

return formattedParticipants;  }
```

Output of 1st print statement

> 0

Output of 2nd print statement

> 3

---

### The Problem

The return is always an empty list. As you can see, the loop and the return statement do not wait for the list to be populated. BUT, if you wait 3 seconds, the list did get populated, but it is too late.

How can I wait, in each iteration of the for loop, for the query to be done AND the .then to be called and completed?

*This method is called in a factory constructor function of a class, therefore futures and awaits cannot be used.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784845/flutter-wait-for-firestore-to-complete, and other related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `await` to wait for the asynchronous `once()` method.

```
//      
static Future<List<FrediUser>> formattedParticipantListFromIDs(List<String> participantIDs) 
async {
//    
  List<FrediUser> formattedParticipants = [];

  for (String id in participantIDs) {
              // 
    var value = await dbQuery(2, 'users', id).once();
    formattedParticipants.add(FrediUser.fromMap(value.snapshot.value as Map));
  }

  print(formattedParticipants.length);

  return formattedParticipants;  
}
```

As you'll see, this means that your `formattedParticipantListFromIDs` function has to be marked as `async`, and returns a `Future`. There is no way to prevent this, as there's no way to make asynchronous code behave synchronously.

For more on this, I recommend taking the Dart codelab on [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: Thank you! So…if I am using this function for a factory function toMap() inside a class, it is not possible to make that async and await for the return value. Therefore, do you recommend changing the factory —> static function so I can use futures?

Comment: Why wouldn't a factory be able to return a `Future`? Is there some rule against that? Or is it because you can't use `await` in the place where you call it? In that, case: did you consider using `then()` to consume the result instead?

Comment: `Factory bodies can't use 'async', 'async*', or 'sync*'. The modifier 'async' can't be applied to the body of a constructor. (Documentation) ` --> this is the error when putting async in the factory constructor function. That is why I was thinking of removing the `Factory` and using it as a normal static method. Then apply the futures as you said. Do you believe that to be the best way?

Comment: "the best" is not clearly defined. But if your current approach doesn't work, that might be one option. Or, as said above, you could use a `then()` clause to process the result of calling `formattedParticipantListFromIDs`.